# Inverse Matrix in Python

Tags: matrices, python

[image]

My understanding is that I can use Python to initialize my matrix and then apply an inverse function to find the solution.

Comment: This question is more suited to StackExchange forum.

Comment: You should solve for $z$ *on paper* using back substitution. Then compute the columns of the inverse matrix, on paper, by making  particular choices for $b_1, b_2, b_3$.

Comment: If you want to solve a linear system of equations in Python, you can have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** use matlab but:

1.) you will get a numerical approximation of the inverse,

2.) you won't learn anything from that.

Rather, try doing what the question asks you - work out what $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are in terms of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ (by writing out the equations and rewriting them a bit) or use any other technique to calculate an inverse of $3\times3$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the three linear equations and solve the system (by hand!). This is quasi-immediate.

Comment: Ok, but, I suppose I should better phrase my question.  How do I solve a matrix [(z2 -z1) , (z3-z2), (0-z3)] = [b1,b2,b3] My confusion stems from the fact that I do not know how to expand the resultant and solve the terms for (b)

Comment: @Adam: Hint: $-z_3=b_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Inverting a matrix:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[-1, 1, 0],[0,-1,1],[0,0,-1]])
b = numpy.linalg.inv(a)

print(a)
print(b)

print(a*b)
```

the output should be:

```
[[-1  1  0]
 [ 0 -1  1]
 [ 0  0 -1]]

[[-1. -1. -1.]
 [-0. -1. -1.]
 [-0. -0. -1.]]

[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

In case of a system of linear equations use an NumPy-Array for your vector:

````
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[-1, 1, 0],[0,-1,1],[0,0,-1]])
b = np.array([20,26,33])

solution = np.linalg.inv(a).dot(b)
```
````

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your notation:

> *deltaz* = [-1 1 0][z1] = [z2 - z1] = [b1] = b [0 -1 1] [z2] [z3 - z2] [b2] [0 0 -1] [z3] [0 - z3] [b3]

Are you attempting Python pseudocode or are you defining a matrix? If the latter, please use MathJax for a more readable format.